# Voltage Comparator Circuit Output 0V or 5V

Tags: comparator

I'd like to build a very simple voltage comparator circuit with the following properties:

- Vs = 5V
- V- = Ground
- Vout = 5V if V+ >= 200mV
- Vout = 0V if V+ < 200mV

I'm using this comparator: NTE943M
http://www.nteinc.com/specs/900to999/pdf/nte943.pdf

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes you can do that. Just apply a 200 mV reference voltage to the inverting input. Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: My output doesn't go to 5V, do I need some pull up resistor or other feedback?

Comment: basically id like to detect a rising edge

Comment: That's a crap datasheet (I'm pretty sure NTE doesn't make their own parts, just repackages other vendors' parts). You'd be better off to get a part with a better datasheet. But yes, it does look like you need a pull-up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NTE934M is a copy of the [LM393](http://www.ti.com.cn/general/cn/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?genericPartNumber=lm393-n&fileType=pdf). Its outputs are 'open collector' and can only pull down. You need a pullup resistor (the datasheet suggests 1.5K).